# What is the significance of Asterisk and Exclamation marks in PERMISSION STATES

Tags: aem

While going through Adobe Documentation on [User Administration and Security](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-0/administer/security/security.html#Permission%20States)

I couldn't understand the meaning and pupose behind Asterisk and Exclamation marks besides the checkbox of permission.

What does local entry mean in this reference and what is effective and ineffective?

I am looking for more explanation and clarification on above.

Answer (score 5):

If a user is part of multiple groups and different groups have different permissions on a particular node. The effective overall permissions are determined by different combinations.

**Local Entry** means that manually permission has been updated on particular node (through useradmin or crx access control panel) instead of permissions getting inherited from ancestor node (e.g. a permission on parent node getting applied to child node).

**Effective Permission** means that a permission is getting applied as per the group permission configuration. e.g. for a group there is "allow" permission on a node and we see that "allow" is shown in useradmin for user who is member of that group.

**Ineffective permission** means that a permission is NOT getting applied as per the group permission configuration. e.g. on a node there are 2 group permissions. For group A its "allow", for group B its "deny" on a particular node. But for a user who is member of both groups, user admin shows "allow" on that node. So in this case effective permission is group A's "allow" and ineffective permission is group B's "deny"

You would see

- (asterisk) only for effective only scenarios. And both *(asterisk) and !(exclamation) for ineffective or effective + ineffective combinations

Permissions can be tricky, follow quote from the link you have shared sums it up. You can also refer [how permissions are evaluated](https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/experience-manager-65/administering/security/user-group-ac-admin.html?lang=en#how-access-rights-are-evaluated)

> Using deny can cause unexpected effects if the permissions are applied
> in a different order than the order expected. If a user is a member of
> more than one group, the Deny statements from one group may cancel the
> Allow statement from another group or vice versa. It is hard to keep
> an overview when this happens and can easily lead to unforeseen
> results, whereas Allow assignments do not cause such conflicts.

Comment: I was not able to edit the post. The link in the post is outdated. Here's the updated one [How Access Rights are evaluated](https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/experience-manager-65/administering/security/user-group-ac-admin.html?lang=en#how-access-rights-are-evaluated)

Comment: Link is updated based on new document path changes